# count from ExecuteScalar() returns 0

Tags: c#, t-sql

I've done some research and everything I'm doing seems to be correct with what other people are suggesting to do. So haven't found yet why this isn't working and when I debug (int)command.ExecuteScalar() shows 0. Even though if I run the query manually - the result being returned in SQL Management Studio is 1.
This is the code snippet I'm trying to get working:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var command = new SqlCommand(@"
select count (distinct ProcessCalled) 
from ETL.ProcessMonitor 
where ProcessCalled = '@package' and ProcessStatusDescription in ('Running','RanToCompletion')
and ProcessStartDateTime > convert(datetime, @processEventDateTime, 120)", connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("processEventDateTime", _lastPackageExecution);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("package", package);
                return (int)command.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }
```

So what is wrong with it? Why (int)command.ExecuteScalar() returns 0 all the time? Cheers.

I've also tried to convert both the datetimes to just dates like so:

```
and cast(ProcessStartDateTime as date) = convert(date, @processEventDateTime, 120)
```

But its still not working in c#, still works in SQL Management

Have also just tried `count(*)`, still not working in c# only

Comment: it could be the problem of `@processEventDateTime`, the time on your c# is not the same as the time on your sql server. That's why in c# it returns 0, while running manually in sql management, it returns 1.

Comment: When I copy-paste the values from all my parameters as they appear in the debug mode in c# - the query passes just fine. I do convert the value in the query to be the exact same format. Cheers

Comment: Yes, Grant, it is 0 :(

Comment: Ojay, OMG you're right! I can't believe how a minor thing like that would just make it all stop. Why wouldn't it show an exception like a sql command invalid, as I'd expect it to then treat the double quotes coming back as escape characters?!?!?! Can you please submit it as a proper answer so I can rate it. Cheers

Comment: It wouldn't show an exception because the sql is perfectly valid `ProcessCalled = '@package'` is a perfectly valid where clause. Chances are fairly slim that you have a ProcessCalled '@Package', hence the zero (0) result. One way to find out exactly the SQL that C# is executing, is start up SQL profiler, execute the code and capture the request, then you will see exactly what SQL C# is passing through, but I'm fairly sure its not adding your package variable at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try remove the quotes from around the `'@package'` in the query, you shouldn't need to do that, the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` will take care of that for you. I do believe quoting it will treat it as a value, not as a parameter, i.e. in essence you are executing the query with `ProcessCalled = '@package'`, literally the string @package.

Also, you should add the @ symbol to your AddWithValues i.e. `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@package", package);`